# Eclipse + PyDev + Django 1.4 - Template directory problems

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I was trying to use a template but it keeps giving me a `TemplateDoesNotExist` exception. If I look at the `Template-loader postmortem`, I notice that it is looking in the wrong directory. It is trying to find templates within my workspace folder and not within the location of the project (outside workspace)

If I try to specify a path in settings, it just appends that path to the workspace path.

I'm quite new to Eclipse and PyDev -- how can I sort this out?

I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2 with PyDev 2.4.0 and Django 1.4

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

At the top of your file, write these two lines:

```
import os
ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Change TEMPLATE_DIRS to be:

```
os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates'),
```

The 'templates' part should be the relative path to your settings file. In my case it is just templates.

You can also use ROOT_PATH anywhere in the settings, along with join, and it's not a bad idea to use it, because this way your settings file is more universal then constrained to the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py file, there should be a `TEMPLATE_DIRS` directive. This is a tuple which allows you to set up multiple directories (see below) or just a single entry, as is usually the case. Set that to the appropriate folder and it should work. If that doesn't check permissions on the folder to ensure the runtime user has access to it and the templates.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    '/var/www/templates/',
    '/opt/myweb/django/templates',
)
```